# load angular ngDragDrop plugin in jsfiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

If I add the external resource [angular drag and drop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/blob/master/src/angular-dragdrop.min.js) via (https://rawgit.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop/master/src/angular-dragdrop.min.js) I get [errors in the console](https://jsfiddle.net/kbt85s6q/11/) by default. What is my mistake?

```
var app = angular.module("treeRepeatApp", ['sf.treeRepeat','ngDragDrop']);
```

Comment: this module requires jqueryUi to function.  plus, you don't appear to have angular included in your fiddle either.

Comment: I expect the dependencies jquery, jquery-ui and angular are loaded automatically. If I load jquery and angular it runs also into some errors (https://jsfiddle.net/kbt85s6q/12/)

Comment: Angular is very particular about the order in which scripts are loaded.  For this reason, I find that jsfiddle is more difficult to work with than some other sites like plunker or codepen when working with angular.  The errors you are getting now are occurring because the scripts are in the wrong order, and you also need to change the javascript preferences to load in head rather than onload.  Removing all the dependencies and adding them one by one in the proper order is the way to fix the current round of errors.

Comment: at the moment, however, this feels less like a programming question and more like a question about how to use a 3rd party website.

Comment: I agree about the order of loading modules but I suppose I already load them in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

I add the angular library in the javascript settings at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbt85s6q/13/) to solve the issue.

```
var app = angular.module("treeRepeatApp", ['sf.treeRepeat', 'ngDragDrop']);
```

[image]